# Creating Storage Queue in Task.Run doubles up my processing time

Tags: c#, .net, azure, task, azure-storage-queues

I have a project that process product feed files into my system. For one certain feed file whole process is taking around 40-50 minutes. Now I have created a `WebJob` to process images from the feed and I'm sending picture urls from my first project to `WebJob` by creating storage client. When I have that to my project, it increased the processing time significantly, so I tried using it with `Task.Run` to use `Fire and Forget` approach, but still even with that overall process time is around 2 hours now.

Here is how I call my method that creates storage queue.

```
if (insertImages)
{
    #pragma warning disable 4014
    Task.Run(async () => { await new QueueUtility().CreateQueueMessage(picture); }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    #pragma warning restore 4014
}
```

And here is my code to create queue message

```
public async Task CreateQueueMessage(Picture picture)
    {
            Utility.Log log = new Utility.Log();
            await AddQueueMessage(picture.url);

    }


public async Task AddQueueMessage(string queueMessage)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ImagekWebJobStorage"));

        // Create the queue client.
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("imagekqueue");

        // Create the queue if it doesn't already exist
        queue.CreateIfNotExists();

        // Create a message and add it to the queue.
        CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(queueMessage);
        queue.AddMessage(message);

    }
```

I don't understand why my processing time doubled up and can't find a way to work around that either. Any ideas that would help me resolve this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1 - you're attempting to create your queue with every call to `AddQueueMessage()`. This is an unnecessary round trip.

2 - try turning off Nagle algorithm, via

`ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm=false;`

Otherwise, smaller tcp packets may be delayed upwards of 1/2-second.

Comment: Yes no need to keep doing that, unless you're creating new queues with each call. Much more efficient to set up queues ahead of time, one time.

Comment: Also each call to Createifnotexists incurs transaction cost billing wise. You could cache it locally after you call that once. Not too much cost but still good to save whatever you can